# Remove page title from Woocommerce shop in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i'm trying to remove the page title from my woocommerce shop page. If i use this css the page title is removed from all pages, this is not what i want.

```
.page-heading h1 {display: none;}
```

So i started looking for a page-id, but it seems the shop is a post, so i used postid of my page

```
.postid-15169 .page-heading h1 {display: none;}
```

but this doesn't work at all

i also tried to put this is my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', false);
```

But this doesn't do anything either. I guess it's not the shop title i'm needing to remove, just the page title.

Any idea what i can do to remove the title for this page only ?
you can find the page here: https://goo.gl/5LNwRR

Comment: `.post-type-archive-product .page-heading h1 {display: none;}` should work and it should be specific enough to not affect the other pages.

Comment: thanks a lot, this works !

Answer (score 1):

I added a ccs code:

```
.page-title-shop h1 {
  display: none;
}
```

It worked for Woocommerce 3.2.x

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using css, you can use woocommerce filter to get the job done.

```
function wc_hide_page_title()
{
    if( !is_shop() ) // is_shop is the conditional tag
        return true;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', 'wc_hide_page_title' );
```

You can remove titles from all woocommerce pages. [Here is a blog post](http://tidyhive.com/remove-page-titles-from-woocommerce-pages/) about this.

Comment: did you try this code?